# How can I sort array into array with key value in php

Tags: php

I want to sort a PHP array that have multiple array with key values.

Sample Array:

```
Array
(
[1240830] => Array
    (
        [name] => Jannah
        [order] => 8
    )

[1240831] => Array
    (
        [name] => Eadie
        [order] => 10
    )

[1240832] => Array
    (
        [name] => abc@yahoo.ca
        [order] => 0
    )

[1240911] => Array
    (
        [name] => on
        [order] => 0
    )

)
```

So I need array that sorted according to `Order` value in ASC. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use `usort` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

`usort($sampleArray, function ($a, $b) { return $a['order'] - $b['order']; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use your simple own function for that by specifying which column you want to use for sorting:

```
    function arr_multisort($arr, $column) {
        $c = array_column($arr, $column);
        array_multisort($c, SORT_ASC, $arr);
        return $arr;
    }
```

In your case:

```
$sortedArray = arr_multisort($originalArray, 'order');
```